# How to set ng-model null on enabling and disabling multiple checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a multiple set of check boxes:-
Clients:-

```
<md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="clients.allwd" class="md-primary md-hue-2" md-no-ink>Allowed</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="clients.add"  class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-disabled="
        !clients.allwd">Add</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="clients.modify" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-disabled="
        !clients.allwd">Modify</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="clients.remove" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-disabled="
        !clients.allwd">Remove</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="clients.view" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-disabled="
        !clients.allwd">View</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="clients.export" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-disabled="
        !clients.allwd">Export</md-checkbox>
```

Roles:-

```
<md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="roles.allwd" class="md-primary md-hue-2" md-no-ink>Allowed</md-checkbox>

    <md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="roles.add"  class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-disabled="
            !roles.allwd">Add</md-checkbox>

    <md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="roles.modify" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-disabled="
            !roles.allwd">Modify</md-checkbox>

    <md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="roles.view" class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-disabled="
            !roles.allwd">View</md-checkbox>
```

and many more.........

If I click on Allowed other checkboxes get enabled otherwise disabled. Let say I checked Allowed checkbox and then Add checkbox and then again check Allowed checkbox, then Add button will remain checked(even though disabled). What I want is if I check Allowed checkbox again then the Add checkbox should be set to null.
One way of doing is:- `scope.add = ""/null`.
But this is not an efficient way to do as I have multiple checkboxes.
Is there a way to achieve this with minimal code?

Comment: I think using the same approach as yours, you would need to change every `ng-model` on allowed checkbox toggle. There could be another approach if you follow second example on this link. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox

Answer (score 0):

you could create object something like this:

```
<md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="checkbox.allwd" class="md-primary md-hue-2" md-no-ink>Allowed</md-checkbox>

<md-checkbox aria-label="role master" ng-model="checkbox.add"  class="md-primary md-hue-2" ng-disabled="
        !allwd">Add</md-checkbox>
```

then in your $onInit you could initialize checkbox object with values if you want - it's not necessary:

```
$scope.checkbox = {
allwd: false,
add: false,
modify: false,
remove: false,
view: false,
export: false,
};
```

after that you can set up function on `$scope`:

```
$scope.clearCheckboxes = () => {
  Object.keys($scope.checkbox).forEach(key=>{
    $scope.checkbox[key] = undefined;
  })
};
```

then just simply call it on button with `ng-click="clearCheckboxes()"` or somewhere in your controller `$scope.clearCheckboxes()`

Keep in mind I didn't have time to test above so it may require some bug fixes.

If you need it for multiple groups you could extend main object to have keys like:

```
$scope.checkboxes = {
    notClients: {
      allwd: true,
      add: false,
      modify: false,
      remove: false,
      view: false,
      export: false,
    },
    clients: {
      allwd: false,
      add: false,
      modify: false,
      remove: false,
      view: false,
      export: false,
    }
  };
```

and then you will also need to extend clear function:

```
$scope.clearCheckboxes = () => {
    Object.keys($scope.checkboxes).forEach(group => {
      Object.keys($scope.checkboxes[group]).forEach(key => {
        $scope.checkboxes[group][key] = false;
      });
    });
  };
```

Here's basic fiddle example using normal checkboxes so you can play around and improve it:

https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/ak0dgwdu/1/

Comment: The above solution is useful for one set of checkbox but I have multiple sets so this is not an efficient way to achieve that.

Comment: Yeah but this is easy to extend to accept multiple checkboxes - I updated answer and added fiddle.